# SQL Error 137 state 2 Class 15, SQL Application not working

Tags: c#, sql

I am Programming a button for a C# application where shows, then let's the user change the details (such as phone number, address) and then it replaces it with the old values in an SQL Database, I'm not so sure if there is something wrong with the SQL code I've written or it's to do with the C# code. Also I am very new to coding; so I am very sorry if my code confuses you.
Connection String---

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connstrng" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-MJ61J7L\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Econtact;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Class Called ContactClass----

```
class contactClass
{
    //getter and setter properties
    //acts as data carrier in our application

    public int ContactID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string ContactNo { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

public bool Update(contactClass c)
    {
        bool isSuccess = false;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstrng);
        try
        {
            string sql = "UPDATE tbl_contact SET FirstName=@FirstName, LastName=@LastName, ContactNo=@ContactNo, Address=@Address, Gender=@Gender WHERE ContactID=@ContactID";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", c.FirstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", c.LastName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo", c.ContactNo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", c.Address);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", c.Gender); 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactID", c.ContactID);
            //open database connection
            conn.Open();

            int row = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (row != 0)
            {
                isSuccess = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isSuccess = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(isSuccess);
        return isSuccess;
    }
```

Update Button (On Click)

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c.FirstName = txtboxFirstName.Text;
        c.LastName = txtboxLastName.Text;
        c.ContactNo = txtboxPhonenumber.Text;
        c.Address = txtboxAddress.Text;
        c.Gender = cmbGender.Text;
        //update data in the database
        bool success = c.Update(c);
        if(success==true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Contact has been successfully updated.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unsuccesfull");
        }
     }
```

Also(just in case) the data pull from the sql database

```
private void dgvContactList_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //get data grid view and load it into textboxes
        //identify which row mouse is clicked
        int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
        txtBoxContactID.Text = dgvContactList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txtboxFirstName.Text = dgvContactList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        txtboxLastName.Text = dgvContactList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txtboxPhonenumber.Text = dgvContactList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        txtboxAddress.Text = dgvContactList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        cmbGender.Text = dgvContactList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: You are missing ContactID `Msg 137, Must declare the scalar variable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `c.ContactID = int.Parse(txtBoxContactID.Text);`
to my btn_UpdateClick function. Thanks for the advice and tips though guys.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare all the variables. Here you missed the variable "@ContactID"

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactID", c.ContactID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify a value for the parameter `@ContactID`.

Solution:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactID", c.ContactID);
```

---

*Aside:* there is a good reason to never use `AddWithValue`: it might use Type `object` instead of a more specific Type that type you might expect to be used, which might cause hard-to-find issues with records not being found or parameter values not being stored correctly.

Rewritten (improved) version:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = c.ContactID;
```

This applies to all SQL parameters, it is better to always use this style of parameter passing.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the ContactId variable. You should also be utilizing USING statements as your current code doesn't free up resources properly, like so:

```
private static void ExecuteSqlCommand(string queryString,
string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
           connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            using(var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
            {
            command.Connection.Open();
            var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            // Do whats needed with the result.
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            //log and/or rethrow or ignore
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            //log and/or rethrow or ignore
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            //log and/or rethrow or ignore
        }
    }
}
```

It's not a flawless example but enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks man for the tip, I will for sure use it next time I Execute SQL Commands.